# How to close a Modal Dialog in Vue3 from another component PimeVue

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vuejs3, primevue

I'm trying to create a Dialog component and use it into another component.
When I click the button, the Dialog opens, but I don't know how to close it.
These are the components:

Dialog:

```
<template>
  <Dialog
    header="###"
    :visible="displayModal"
    :breakpoints="{ '960px': '75vw', '640px': '90vw' }"
    :style="{ width: '50vw' }"
    :modal="true"
  >
    <div class="container">
      // Dialog content
    <template #footer>
      <Button
        label="Close"
        class="p-button p-button-secondary"
        icon="pi pi-times"
        @click="closeModal"
      />
      <Button
        label="Guardar"
        class="p-button p-button-primary"
        icon="pi pi-check"
        autofocus
        v-model:visible="displayModal"
      />
    </template>
  </Dialog>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits, ref } from "vue";

defineEmits(["update:visible"]);
const displayModal = ref(false);
const closeModal = () => {
  displayModal.value = false;
};

</script>
```

The other component:

```
<template>
     // Some code
        <SplitButton
          class="datatable-button"
          icon="pi pi-pencil"
          label="XXX"
          :model="XXX"
          @click="openModal"
        />
    <ModalDialog v-model:visible="displayModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import ModalDialog from "@/components/modal/ModalDialog.vue";
import { ref } from "vue";
//Modal
const displayModal = ref(false);

const openModal = () => {
  displayModal.value = true;
  console.log("DisplayModal: ", displayModal.value);
};
</script>
```

I've tried using emits but i'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `closeModal` with

```
const closeModal = () => {
  emit("update:visible", false);
};
```

And add by `ModalDialog` v-on `@update:visible="closeDialog($event)"`

```
  const closeDialog = (value) => {
    displayModal.value = value;
    console.log("DisplayModal: ", displayModal.value);
  };
```

### Playground

```js
const {createApp, ref, defineProps, defineEmits } = Vue;

const ModalDialog = {
  components: {
      'p-button': primevue.button,
      'p-dialog': primevue.dialog
  },
  props: ['visible'],
  setup(props, { attrs, slots, emit, expose }) {
    defineEmits(["update:visible"]);
    const closeModal = () => {
      emit("update:visible", false);
    };
     return {
          closeModal
     };
  },
  template: '#modal-dialog'
}

const App = {
  setup() {
      const displayModal = ref(false);
      const openModal = () => {
        displayModal.value = true;
        console.log("DisplayModal: ", displayModal.value);
      };
      const closeDialog = (value) => {
        displayModal.value = value;
        console.log("DisplayModal: ", displayModal.value);
      };
      return {
          displayModal, openModal, closeDialog
      };
  },
  components: {
      ModalDialog,
      'p-button': primevue.button,
      'p-dialog': primevue.dialog
  }
};

createApp(App).use(primevue.config.default).mount("#app");
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
.comment { color: #A0A0A0}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/themes/lara-light-indigo/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
displayModal: {{displayModal}}<br/>
 <p-button
    class="datatable-button"
    icon="pi pi-pencil"
    label="XXX"
    @click="openModal"
  ></p-button>
  <modal-dialog :visible="displayModal" @update:visible="closeDialog($event)" />    
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/core/core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/button/button.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="modal-dialog">
<p-dialog
    header="###"
    v-model:visible="visible"
    :breakpoints="{ '960px': '75vw', '640px': '90vw' }"
    :style="{ width: '50vw' }"    
  >                   
     <template #footer>
        <p-button
        label="Close"
        class="p-button p-button-secondary"
        icon="pi pi-times"
        @click="closeModal()"
      ></p-button>
      <p-button
        label="Guardar"
        class="p-button p-button-primary"
        icon="pi pi-check"
        autofocus
        v-model:visible="displayModal"
      ></p-button>
    </template>
  </p-dialog>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved doing this:
All the logic belongs to the parent, the child only emits the event.

**Parent:**

```
  <template>
    <ModalDialog
      :visible="displayModal"
      @close-modal="closeModal"
    />
  </template>
    
  <script setup lang "ts">
    const displayModal = ref(false);
    
    const openModal = () => {
      displayModal.value = true;
    };
    
    const closeModal = () => {
      displayModal.value = false;
    };
  </script>
```

**Child:**

```
  <template>
    <Dialog :visible="visible">
    //some code
    </Dialog>
  <template>

  <script setup lang="ts">
    const emit = defineEmits(["closeModal"]);
    
    defineProps({
      visible: {
      type: Boolean,
      },
    });
    
    const closeModal = () => {
      emit("closeModal");
    };
  </script>
```